# using imwrite in cv2 saves a black image

Tags: python, image, opencv

I am working on a game project about image neutral-style models. In my code, the imshow function shows the correct image, but the imwrite function saves a completely black image. Is there a solution to fix this? I am using python.

```
net.setInput(blob)
out=net.forward()
out=out.reshape(3,out.shape[2],out.shape[3])
out[0]+=103.939
out[1]+=116.779
out[2]+=123.68
out/=225
out=out.transpose(1,2,0)

cv2.imshow('bg',out)
cv2.imwrite('images/bg/%sBg.png'%uploadImg[:-4],out)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Looks like your image is floating point with values in range [0,1]. `imshow` will scale it by 255 before conversion to 8bit in order to display it. `imwrite` will just convert to 8bit without scaling (so you're left with a bunch of 0s and 1s which look all black). I suppose easiest fix is to `imwrite` `out * 255`.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much!!